# How to make JS execution wait?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension

[This is my content and background.js trying to communicate with each other](http://pastebin.com/MrkSheiH)
I am getting the below error in background.js:

Error in event handler for (unknown): TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
    at chrome-extension://ijdejodkcfeliecedikgogpmnkjienlh/background.js:107:67handler @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:8(anonymous function) @ extensions::uncaught_exception_handler:100EventImpl.dispatch_ @ extensions::event_bindings:376EventImpl.dispatch @ extensions::event_bindings:393target.(anonymous function) @ extensions::SafeBuiltins:19publicClass.(anonymous function) @ extensions::utils:94dispatchOnDisconnect @ extensions::messaging:296

Comment: Go with the `DOMContentLoaded` event..Not sure how it works with `chrome-extensions`

Comment: one way is to wait for the DOM to be loaded ... document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {... your code ...})` - another way is to put the javascript at the bottom of the body tag

Comment: with chrome-extensions, there's a config option which indicates when to run the script, it's name is `run-at` but I don't know the values it can contain

Comment: This is very common and duplicate question, try googling , jquery onload, ready etc

Comment: "Now as you can see"?  You've given us nothing to go on.  Facebook?  Logged in?  Make this an [mcve] and you might get something more informative.

Comment: @Teepeemm ...I have added both content.js and background.js in the above link....please have a look at it and respond.

Comment: You should post the code here, not behind a pastebin link.  But remove the comments to simplify what you're posting.  What you have looks ok, except that you can't tell what triggers the message from the background script.

Answer (score 0):

For a Chrome extension, make the script a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) and use the `run_at` option in your manifest to control when it runs; you probably want `'document_end'`:

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded.

In general, there are a few ways:

1. Simply put the code *after* the markup for the DOM elements it acts on. Usually, unless you have a good reason to do somethign else, your `script` tags should go at the **end** of your document, just before the closing `</body>` tag. All of the elements defined by the markup above that are accessible at that point.

   This is, of course, what `run_at: 'document_end'` is basically doing.
2. Put the code in a callback executed when the elements are available, such as the `DOMContentLoaded` event or (much later) the `window.load` event. If you're using jQuery, it offers a `ready` callback that uses `DOMContentLoaded` (if it can) and falls back to other mechanisms (if it can't).
3. Detect that you've gotten back `null` and schedule the code to run again in a moment using `setTimeout`.

For me, those are in descending order of usefulness. By far, the simplest and most general solution is #1.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an asynchronous JavaScript script that checks for the element every 50ms until it exists.

However, this should only be used to wait until the element appears when you know that it will, because it constantly checks for the element, which impacts the performance on the end users side.

You can Increase, or decrease the loop speed at the end of the script.

```
  // Sets a timer that loops for the time at the end until the following element is found
  var checkExist = setInterval(function() {
    // Define element to look for
    var elementExists = document.querySelector("div.AGUW54C-d-W a");
    // Chcek if element exists
    if (elementExists !== undefined) {
      // One the element is found, stop the loop
      clearInterval(checkExist);
      // Run following code when element exists

    }
  }, 50); // Check every 50ms
```

You should make sure that your Content Script runs at `document_end` to mitigate the performance hit from the script above.

> In the case of "document_end", the files are injected immediately after the DOM is complete, but before subresources like images and frames have loaded. - [Google Chrome Documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at)

Answer (score -2):

Use Jquery methods on load and ready:

[Load](https://api.jquery.com/load-event/) or 
[Ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/)